# Using storyboards to navigate a complex set of views, unwind segue is not enough

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

[image]I have a storyboard that looks like the attached image.

The idea is that there are three portrait views, showing current consumption, through which the user can navigate by swiping left. I'm using left swipe gesture recognisers for this. Then I add right swipe gesture recognisers and connect then to an unwind segue to go back. This works fine.

The order is [both electricity & gas] -> [electricity] -> [gas].

Each portrait view has a corresponding landscape detail view. These are also set up so that the user can navigate by swiping, and I unwind the segues so that they can swipe back. Again the order is [both graph] -> [electricity graph] -> [gas graph].

I also want the user to be able to move from any portrait view to its corresponding detail view by rotating the device. I spot the rotation in each of the portrait controllers, and programmatically perform the segue, like so (for gas). (Note the code isn't robust against the correct orientation yet, while I'm just experimenting.)

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)aToInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)aDuration {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueGasToLandscape" sender:self];
}
```

So, for example, the user might swipe twice to view the gas portrait page, and then rotate the device to see the detailed graph of gas consumption.

From here, I'd like the user to be able to swipe right to see the electricity detail graph, and then right again to the graph for both - but this won't happen, as the method for doing this is to unwind a swipe that has not happened. (And in fact the landscape electricity view controller is not even instantiated at this point.)

What I think I need is not to use unwind segues, but instead to use normal segues throughout. However I want to do this without creating new instantiations for existing controllers (as unwind segues do) but to create a new instantiation if needed (as unwind segues don't).

If it matters, I'm happy to code for iOS 6.1 and above.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: Check out this blog post. You basically need to check the current orientation to decide which VC to pop to. http://vastdevblog.vast.com/blog/2012/02/12/rotating-to-show-different-ios-views/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use InstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:  Dont forget to set the Storyboard ID of the receiving view controller.

```
if (!self.homeVC)
{
    self.homeVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeView"];
    [self presentViewController:self.homeVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```